# Javascript não carrega ao linka-lo na tag script

Tags: javascript, script

Eu criei uma classe js para diminuir as linhas e não ter muitos scripts, então criei a 'main.js', para colocar todos os js, que depois seria linkada a partir do script src. só que quando eu linko, nada funciona, e o diretório está correto... testei colocando todos os js dentro da tag script, e td funciona normalmente.

Estes são meus java scripts e todos estão no diretório correto:

```
<!-- Javascripts-->

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/frontend-edit.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mixitup.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
```

E aqui está meu main.js:

```
 // WOW animate
new WOW().init();

 // Facebook script
 (function(d, s, id) {
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10';
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

 // Go to top

   $(window).scroll(function() {
       if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50) { // If page is scrolled more than 50px
               $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn(200);    // Fade in the arrow
           } else {
           $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut(200);   // Else fade out the arrow
           }
        });
        $('.scrollToTop').click(function() {      // When arrow is clicked
           $('body,html').animate({
               scrollTop : 0                       // Scroll to top of body
           }, 500);
        });

 jQuery(function($) {
  "use strict"; // Start of use strict
  // debugger

// Navigation Scroll
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    Scroll();
});

$('.navbar-collapse ul li a').on('click', function() {  
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - 64}, 1250);
    return false;
 });

// User define function
function Scroll() {
    var contentTop      =   [];
    var contentBottom   =   [];
    var winTop      =   $(window).scrollTop();
    var rangeTop    =   200;
    var rangeBottom =   500;
    $('.navbar-collapse').find('.scroll a').each(function(){
        contentTop.push( $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top);
        contentBottom.push( $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top + $( 
 $(this).attr('href') ).height() );
    })
    $.each( contentTop, function(i){
        if ( winTop > contentTop[i] - rangeTop ){
            $('.navbar-collapse li.scroll')
            .removeClass('active')
            .eq(i).addClass('active');          
        }
    })
};

var hash = window.location.hash;
scrollToElem(hash);

// Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
$('body').scrollspy({
    target: '.navbar-fixed-top',
    offset: 51
});

// Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
$('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
});

// Offset for Main Navigation
$('#main-navbar').affix({
    offset: {
        top: 100
    }
})

// Initialize and Configure Scroll Reveal Animation
window.sr = ScrollReveal();
sr.reveal('.sr-icons', {
    duration: 600,
    scale: 0.3,
    distance: '0px'
}, 200);
sr.reveal('.sr-button', {
    duration: 1000,
    delay: 200
});
sr.reveal('.sr-contact', {
    duration: 600,
    scale: 0.3,
    distance: '0px'
}, 300);

// Initialize and Configure Magnific Popup Lightbox Plugin
$('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type: 'image',
    tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
    mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
    gallery: {
        enabled: true,
        navigateByImgClick: true,
        preload: [0, 1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
    },
    image: {
        tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.'
    }
});

  })(jQuery); // End of use strict

 // Animated Header on Scroll //
 var cbpAnimatedHeader = (function() {

  var docElem = document.documentElement,
    header = document.querySelector( '.navbar-fixed-top' ),
    didScroll = false,
    changeHeaderOn = 10;

function init() {
    window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function( event ) {
        if( !didScroll ) {
            didScroll = true;
            setTimeout( scrollPage, 250 );
        }
    }, false );
}

function scrollPage() {
    var sy = scrollY();
    if ( sy >= changeHeaderOn ) {
        classie.add( header, 'navbar-shrink' );
     }
     else {
         classie.remove( header, 'navbar-shrink' );
     }
     didScroll = false;
 }

 function scrollY() {
     return window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop;
 }

 init();

})();

// Stellar //

$.stellar({
    // Set scrolling to be in either one or both directions
    horizontalScrolling: false,
    verticalScrolling: true,
});

// Counter - Contador //
$('.counter').counterUp({
    delay: 10,
    time: 2000
});

// Loader

 $(window).load(function() {
     // Animate loader off screen
     $(".page-loader").fadeOut("slow");
 });

// Owl intro
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-text").owlCarousel({

  navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
  slideSpeed : 300,
  paginationSpeed : 400,
  singleItem:true

  // "singleItem:true" is a shortcut for:
  // items : 1, 
  // itemsDesktop : false,
  // itemsDesktopSmall : false,
  // itemsTablet: false,
  // itemsMobile : false

  });

});
```

Comment: Qual erro esta aparecendo no console?

Comment: Vc colocou tudo na ordem certa?

Comment: De cara já posso ver um provável problema: o `new WOW().init();` é chamado antes de ser carregado o plugin, que está lá embaixo: `<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>`